# Tunnel Gre between two hosts (vps and dedicated server)

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, centos, tunnel

Hello guys i need to resolve this problem (all server have installed centos 7): i'm trying to create a gre tunnel through vps (in Italy - OpenVZ) and a dedicated server (in Germany), but they do not communicate internally (ping and ssh command tests). Next i create a gre tunnel trought vps (in Italy - OpenVZ) and vps (in France - KVM OpenStack) and their communicate, i next i had create a tunnel trought vps (in France - KVM OpenStack) and a dedicated server (in Germany) their communicate. I can not understand why the vps (in Italy - OpenVZ) and the dedicated server (in Germany) do not communicate, ideas on how I can fix (
I also tried with iptables disabled, firewalld is not enable)? Thanks

**In other words:**

In other attempts (by this i mean that i managed to successfully create the GRE Tunnel between these machines):

- The VPS (in France) and VPS (in Italy) communicate internally (ping and ssh command tests)
- The VPS (in France) and Dedicated Server (in Germany) communicate internally (ping and ssh command tests)

Problem (by this i mean that i could not successfully create the GRE Tunnel between these machines):

- The VPS (in Italy) and Dedicated Server (in Germany) do not communicate internally (ping and ssh command tests). I also asked hosting services if they had any restrinzione but nothing.

**My configuration:**

1. VPS command for tunnel:

   > echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
   >
   > iptunnel add gre1 mode gre local VPS_IP remote DEDICATED_SERVER_IP ttl 255
   >
   > ip addr add 192.168.168.1/30 dev gre1 ip link set gre1 up
2. Dedicated server command for tunnel:

   > iptunnel add gre1 mode gre local DEDICATED_SERVER_IP remote VPS_IP ttl 255
   >
   > ip addr add 192.168.168.2/30 dev gre1
   >
   > ip link set gre1 up

```
[root@VPS ~]# ping 192.168.168.2
PING 192.168.168.2 (192.168.168.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.168.2 ping statistics ---
89 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 87999ms
```

```
[root@DE ~]# ping 192.168.168.1
PING 192.168.168.1 (192.168.168.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.168.1 ping statistics ---
92 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 91001ms
```

```
[root@VPS ~]# lsmod | grep gre
ip_gre                  4242  -2
ip_tunnel               4242  -2 sit,ip_gre
gre                     4242  -2 ip_gre
```

```
[root@DE ~]# lsmod | grep gre
ip_gre                 22707  0
ip_tunnel              25163  1 ip_gre
gre                    13144  1 ip_gre
```

Comment: Can you confirm using tcpdump that both hosts are sending GRE packets, or even receiving each other's GRE packets?

Comment: @grawity `[root@VPS ~]# tcpdump -A -i gre1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on gre1, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel`

In both server i have this

Comment: I was asking about GRE tunnel packets themselves (so `tcpdump -i eth0 "proto gre"` or `tcpdump -i eth0 "proto 47"`).

Comment: @grawity `[root@VPS ~]# tcpdump -i venet0 "proto gre"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on venet0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
1 packet received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel`
---
`[root@DE ~]# tcpdump -i enp2s0 "proto gre"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel` -- Nothing man

Comment: @grawity can you help me?